# Resources in WPF not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, reload

I'm using the resources to make my wpf application avaible in other languages, so I added this to my 
MainWindow.xaml

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MusicApp.Properties"
```

and this to an example button in the .xaml

```
Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Test}"
```

Originally my Resources.resx only have one line:

```
name -> Value
Test -> testing
```

and the button text was "testing" all good, but now I changed the line to

```
Prueba -> probando
```

and the .xaml to:

```
Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Prueba}"
```

and now I got this error (translated from spanish so it could be wrong)

cannot access to member "Prueba"

Obviously Resources is public, but if I change back the .xaml to the old one (with Test) It's still working although Test is deleted from Resources.

I think Visual studio is not reloading the form or something, any idea?

Comment: Now I'm getting errors on Resources.resx any way to create it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your not binding the value, instead you just assigning the value for the text... So try the below...

```
 Text="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Resources.Prueba}}"
```